# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when trying to get element with nonexisting parent

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I've recently started with Linq, and I'm currently trying to use it to parse a heavily nested XML file (which I have no control over). However, I get the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error when trying to run the below statement.

The problem is in the "City" line. The data for the city property comes from the xml structure prospect/contactinfo/City/Answer.

But since the field is not mandatory, sometimes the XML will NOT have the city/answer nodes. So I get the error because the "city" node does not exist, and I'm trying to call ".Element()" on it. I've found plenty of solutions for this problem, when it is only one node-level down (i.e. if the data I needed was in city, and city was the only node missing).

But when it is two levels down (I.e. trying to get the childnode of a nonexisting node), I have not been able to find any solution.

Hope the question is expressed clearly enough.

Best regards,
Morten

```
            var prospects = (from prospect in xdoc.Descendants("PROSPECT")
                        select new Prospect {
                            ProspectID = (string) prospect.Element("PROSPECTINFO").Element("PROSPECT_ID"),
                            Name = (string) prospect.Element("PERSONALINFO").Element("FIRSTNAME")+ " " + prospect.Element("PERSONALINFO").Element("SURNAME"),
                            address = (string) prospect.Element("CONTACTINFO").Element("ADDRESSLINE1").Element("ANSWER"),
                            zipCode = (string)prospect.Element("CONTACTINFO").Element("POSTALCODE").Element("ANSWER").Value,
                            City = (string) prospect.Element("CONTACTINFO").Element("CITY").Element("ANSWER"),                                
                        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use `Elements` instead of `Element`. That's an extension method which finds *all* elements (optionally with a given name) within either a single element or in a collection of elements. So if you use that repeatedly, you'll end up with a collection of 0 elements at the end if there aren't any matches. Use `FirstOrDefault` to get that element or null, and then the string conversion will do what you want:

```
// Still use Element for CONTACTINFO as presumably that's a required element
City = (string) prospect.Element("CONTACTINFO")
                        .Elements("CITY")
                        .Elements("ANSWER")
                        .FirstOrDefault()
```

That way you don't have to write any conditional code - it all just drops out.

The biggest advantage of this over the sort of check that ChrisF suggests is if the navigation path becomes long. Imagine there are 6 parts of the path, and every one of them is option - you'd need 5 checks (first "a", then "a.b", then "a.b.c" etc) followed by the real "fetch the thing", whereas in this scheme you just add one extra `Elements` call for each new navigation link.

Answer (score 2):

If any nodes can be null then you have to cope with that in your code.

You mention the "CITY" node, so taking that as an example:

```
var prospects = (from prospect in xdoc.Descendants("PROSPECT")
                    select new Prospect {
                        ProspectID =
 (string)prospect.Element("PROSPECTINFO").Element("PROSPECT_ID"),
                        Name =
 (string)prospect.Element("PERSONALINFO").Element("FIRSTNAME")+ " " + prospect.Element("PERSONALINFO").Element("SURNAME"),
                        address =
 (string)prospect.Element("CONTACTINFO").Element("ADDRESSLINE1").Element("ANSWER"),
                        zipCode =
 (string)prospect.Element("CONTACTINFO").Element("POSTALCODE").Element("ANSWER").Value,
                        City =
 prospect.Element("CONTACTINFO").Element("CITY") != null ?
     (string)prospect.Element("CONTACTINFO").Element("CITY").Element("ANSWER") :
     string.Empty,
   }).ToList();
```

You need to check that element is not null before trying to deference it and then if it is null select a default value to assign to the property.

Repeat this for all the elements that can be null.

Putting the check into a method (like Mike suggests) is a good way to keep the code clean. It also means you can extend the check quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a generic function to get the value for any element you specify with NULL checking. Here is an example:

```
public string GetXMLElementValue(XmlElement xElem, params string[] elementsNest)
{
    XmlElement tempElem = xElem;

    foreach (string s in elementsNest)
    {
        if (tempElem.Element(s) == null)
            return string.Empty;
        else
            tempElem = tempElem.Element(s);
    }

    return (string) tempElem;
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
var prospects = (from prospect in xdoc.Descendants("PROSPECT")
    select new Prospect {
        . . .
        City = GetXMLElementValue(prospect, "CONTACTINFO", "CITY", "ANSWER"),          
}).ToList();
```

NOTE: This is untested code, but gives the general idea. You may have to have other parameters in the function to specify if you want to call '.Value' or other methods on the Element.

Comment: I was not aware that it was possible to call methods from within a select new statement. That's amazing!